# Saving additional data to a user profile in Django

Tags: python, django

I've already enabled the ability for users to create profiles; however, I need to be able to save additional data to the profile once the user has already logged in.

Say that John is logged in. After he logs in, he decides that he wants to bookmark a certain term. Every time that he bookmarks a term (the url of the current page), it will be added to the "terms" section associated with his profile.

I'm not sure how to allow for the addition of more than one term - don't think CharField is correct, and I also don't know how to link the form in the template to the view so that it actually saves this data to the profile. Here is what I currently have:

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    terms = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

views.py

This is how I created my user:

```
def register(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            profile.save()

            registered = True

        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()


    return render_to_response(
            'app/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
        context)
```

And this is what I'm attempting to do with terms:

```
def terms(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    url = request.get_full_path()

    profile = UserProfile()
    profile.topics = url
    profile.save() 

    return render_to_response('app/page1.html', {}, context)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^terms/$', views.terms, name='terms'),
```

And the template file.

```
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'terms' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm think you can use https://github.com/brosner/django-bookmarks to save bookmarks for any user without your code. 
Or add model smt about Term like this

```
class Term(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='terms')
    term = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

and use user.terms.all() for get all user's terms.

But, if you need save your schema and models, you need custom field which will works like array field in postgres. If you use postgresql db, add https://github.com/ecometrica/django-dbarray to you project and use terms like TextArrayField, if you db is not postgres see here - 
[What is the most efficent way to store a list in the Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110153/what-is-the-most-efficent-way-to-store-a-list-in-the-django-models) 
second answer titled "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." by user jb.

Solution with relations is "normalized" - simple and strong

Solution with "array-field" is "demormalized" - faster but with risks of non-consistently data.