# Most efficient Django model to store numerical data

Tags: django

What is the best way to store numerical data as a model in Django?  I did look at [What is the most efficent way to store a list in the Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110153/what-is-the-most-efficent-way-to-store-a-list-in-the-django-models), but I'd be curious to hear an answer tailored to numpy arrays as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to convert the numpy array to a string and store it in a textfield

```
base64.encodestring(nparray)
```

Another way would be to dump an array into a file and storing the path of the text file in the database

```
nparray.dump(file)
```

If you want to store the data in a structured manner in Django, you will need to create models to do that.

You could use 2 Models:

```
class Element(models.Model):
    Value = models.FloatField()
    Array = models.ForeignKey(Array)

class Array(models.Model):
    #Not required, just for illustration, use the id models instead
    Name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)

    Parent = models.ForeignKey(self, blank=True, null=True)
```

You store the values in the Element model and create the structure using the Array model.

Say you have a 2D array you can store it this way
    [Array1, Array2, Array3]
    Array1 = [1,2,3]
    Array2 = [4,5,6]
    Array3 = [7,8,9]

```
Array('ParnetArray')

Array('Array1','ParentArray'),Array('Array2','ParentArray'),Array('Array3','ParentArray')

Element(1,'Array1'),Element(2,'Array1'),Element(3,'Array1'),Element(4',Array2'),Element(5,'Array2')...........
```

Comment: Is a textfield the "right" way to do things, though?  If I used a textfield, presumably I would not be able to add data to the list with the Django admin panel.