# where to save the custom field class in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, package

I am confused about the second answer in this post:

[What is the most efficent way to store a list in the Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110153/what-is-the-most-efficent-way-to-store-a-list-in-the-django-models)

For the custom field SeparatedValuesField, which directory I should put this py so I can import from custom.fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That answer assumes that you have a Python file named `fields.py` in a package named `custom` under your project root. ie:

```
/project root
---manage.py
---/custom
------__init__.py
------fields.py
```

You can put your `fields.py` under any existing app and import from that location. For example, if you have an app called `myapp`, you can put the `fields.py` under that package and rewrite your import statement as:

```
from myapp.fields import SeparatedValuesField
```