# Getting 0 when using json.decode

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I am a beginner in Django as well as Python.

I first generate 50 random numbers and store them in a list and then in a text field in model User.

```
def generate(request, user_id):
    easy = [] * 55
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < 50:
        random_id = random.randint(1, 200)
        if random_id not in easy:
            easy.append(random_id)
            cnt += 1
    current_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    current_user.question_array = json.dumps(easy)
    return render(request, 'comp/question.html', {'easy': easy[0], 'question_id': 1,'user_id':user_id})
```

But when I try to retrieve the value from field I get only 0.

When I try to use it as a list it shows an error of "int object cannot be subscript".

This is the code to retrieve it:

```
def next(request,user_id, question_id):
    current_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    jsonDec = json.decoder.JSONDecoder()
    easy = jsonDec.decode(current_user.question_array)
    return render(request, 'comp/question.html',
                  {'easy': easy, 'question_id': int(question_id) + 1,'user_id':user_id})
```

I have used the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110153/what-is-the-most-efficent-way-to-store-a-list-in-the-django-models) question given by mindthief to store a list in a table.

Edit:

My main problem is that the list is not getting stored in database. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `.save()` call to save the data to the db:

```
current_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
current_user.question_array = json.dumps(easy)
current_user.save()
...
```

BTW, you can also use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
easy = random.sample(range(200), 50)  # in python 2.x use xrange()
```

and `json.loads()`:

```
easy = json.loads(current_user.question_array)
```

If you use PostgreSQL (highly recommended) you can even use a [JsonField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield).

And finally, if the questions are stored in another model (`Question`), consider using a `ManyToManyField` instead.

Comment: i don't know much about database. Just started learning from youtube from thenewboston django tutorials. So dont know anything about sqlite3 or PostgresSQL. Thanks for random.sample really helped me reduce the code!