# How can I store multiple values in one field of a Django model? Like an array, list, etc

Tags: python, django

I currently have a "Financing" Django model which currently has multiple attributes like amount, date and so on, on top of that I have a "Quota" model that has similar values and a foreign key (many-to-one) relationship with the Financing model (as in multiple quotas per financing). My question is, is there a way to store said quotas in an array-like field so I can easily access them from the parent financing for referencing later?

I would love to visualize them in their respective "Financing" tab in the admin panel or to fetch them with a for loop like you can do with regular Python arrays.

EDIT: I solved this by using Django's inline admin model, it's not my ideal solution but it works well enough. You'll need to define an Inline class in your admin file to then be called to your actual model's class.

found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Here is the simplified code in case it helps:

```
class UserFinancing(BaseModel):

amount = models.DecimalField(
    _("Amount"),
    max_digits=18,
    decimal_places=2,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)

periods = models.IntegerField(
    _("Weeks"),
    default=6,
    null=True,
    blank=True
)

num_of_quotas = models.IntegerField(
    _("Number of quotas"),
    default=6,
    null=True,
    blank=True
)

is_completed = models.BooleanField(
    _("Is completed?"),
    default=False
)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("User Financing")
    verbose_name_plural = _("User Financings")


class UserQuota(BaseModel):

user_financing = models.ForeignKey(
    UserFinancing,
    verbose_name=_("User financing"),
    related_name='user_quotas',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

amount = models.DecimalField(
    _("Amount"),
    max_digits=18,
    decimal_places=2,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    help_text=_("Amount of the financing option")
)

date_payment = models.DateField(
    _("Date payment"),
    help_text=_("Max date to be payed")
)

date_start = models.DateField(
    _("Date start"),
    help_text=_("Min date to be start paying"),
    null=True,
    default=None,
)

paid = models.BooleanField(
    _("Paid"),
    default=False
)

number = models.IntegerField(
    _("Number"),
    help_text=_("Quota number"),
    default=1,
)

def __str__(self):
    return ('\n#' + str(self.number))

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("User Quota")
    verbose_name_plural = _("User Quotas")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply use `user_financing_object.user_quotas`? The related_name lets you refer to them directly (as opposed to user_financing_object.userquota_set) and then you can loop through them as you would any queryset.

Comment: @Grimidk check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110153/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-a-list-in-the-django-models/49871886#49871886

Comment: @SamSparx I haven't been able to call the reverse relation with the admin panel, at least for the "fields" section, if I'm assuming correctly you mean `user_financing.objects.user_quotas`

Comment: @Ahtisham I don't think this will work since the "parent" class being financing is defined first in order to be used as a foreign key, therefore I can't call quotas back in the parent, at least I don't think so.